# Referencing external workbook in function

Tags: excel, udf, vba

I want to have a function that refer to a external workbook. I wrote this Code but I receive "Run-Time error '9".

```
Function SiteStatus(Arg1 As String) As String
    Dim RFSTable As Workbook
    Dim RFSSheet As Worksheet
    Dim RFSSites As Range
    Set RFSTable = Workbooks("D:\RFS.xlsx")
    Set RFSSheet = RFSTable.Worksheets(3)
    Set RFSSites = RFSSheet.Range("B2:B10000")
        If WorksheetFunction.IsNA(WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Arg1, RFSSites, 1, 0)) = False Then
        SiteStatus = "ÎÇãæÔ"
        Else
        SiteStatus = "ÑæÔä"
        End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not opening the external workbook. If you want to reference a closed external workbook, you still need to open and read the information. Once it is opened, you also need to close the external workbook. Since you are only trying to determine if a cell exists in a single column the worksheet's [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) is a better fit.

```
Function SiteStatus(Arg1 As String) As String
    With Workbooks.Open(Filename:="D:\RFS.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)
        With .Worksheets(3)
            With .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
                If IsError(Application.Match(Arg1, .Cells, 0)) Then
                    SiteStatus = "ÑæÔä"
                Else
                    SiteStatus = "ÎÇãæÔ"
                End If
            End With
        End With
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
End Function
```

The `.Worksheets(3)` reference is dangerous. All it takes would be for someone to reorder the workshets to their preferred queue order in order to break the function.

Why do you need a UDF? The [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) can make a call to a closed external workbook if you specify the Worksheet [.Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196974.aspx).